# mysql how to enhance the name fuzzy matching

Tags: java, mysql, indexing

There are 30000000 rows stored in DB. all the rows contains firstName and lastName.
I'd like to query the data by firstName or lastName but I found that some lastName contain special character which can not be queried currently there are both normal firstName and lastName index

Example: `Susanna [Von Essen] ,Susanna VonEssen , Susanna Von Essen`
Different lastName contain special character, so is there any way I can enhance to query these 3 kinds of name (same lastName)?

Simulation ideal result :
query:`select *from provider where lastName like 'Von%'`
result:`Susanna Von Essen,Susanna [Von Essen],Susanna VonEssen`

query:`select *from provider where lastName like 'Von Essen%'`
result:`Susanna Von Essen,Susanna [Von Essen],Susanna VonEssen`

Thanks!

Comment: There is SOUNDEX() function which will return string similar in phonetic https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex . See also http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/mysql-fuzzy-text-searching-using-the-soundex-function.html but I think MySQL not very good at fuzzy search. I will suggest Elasticsearch for this kind of purpose.

Comment: function does not support index search, this will make the search slowly , elasticsearch is ok but db migration is impossible now

Answer (score 0):

try:

select * from provider where lastName like '%Von%'

select * from provider where lastName like '%Von%Essen%'

Answer (score 0):

`SOUNDEX` is very primitive; I would not use it for anything.

I recommend that, as you insert rows, you construct another column with a "canonical" form of the name.  Examples: remove brackets, remove spaces, duplicate text in multiple likely forms, etc.  Then use `FULLTEXT` to do the search since there will be multiple "words" in the column.

That will cover *some* "fuzzy" cases.  You can adapt it to catch more an more cases.